# Get sum of values which have same value for key php array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have below array,

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [report_id] => 1 [amount] => 100.00 [category_name] => Trial1 ) [1] => Array ( [report_id] => 1 [amount] => 150.00 [category_name] => Trial2 ) [2] => Array ( [report_id] => 1 [amount] => 200.00 [category_name] => Trial2 )
```

What i want to send to have JSON with below format

It will get some of Equal category name and then send it as json.

```
[{'category_name': 'Trial1', 'Sum':100]}, {'category_name':'Trial2', 'Sum':350]
```

How can i achieve this?
Was thinking to get `foreach` loop and then make compare of category_name and use .=+ to get sum? but i lost there,

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below solution:

```
<?php
$array = array ( 
'0' => Array ( 'report_id' => 1, 'amount' => '100.00', 'category_name' => 'Trial1' ) ,
'1' => Array ( 'report_id' => 1, 'amount' => '150.00' ,'category_name' => 'Trial2' ),
'2' => Array ( 'report_id' => 1, 'amount' => '200.00' ,'category_name' => 'Trial2' ) ,
);

$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $a){
    if(!isset($new_array[$a['category_name']]['amount'])){
        $new_array[$a['category_name']]['amount'] = 0;
    }
    $new_array[$a['category_name']] = array(
        'category_name' => $a['category_name'],
        'amount' => $new_array[$a['category_name']]['amount'] + $a['amount'],
    );
}

//print_r(array_values($new_array));

echo json_encode(array_values($new_array));
```

**Output**

```
[{"category_name":"Trial1","amount":100},{"category_name":"Trial2","amount":350}]
```

Comment: Perfect! Works as required

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

```
$categoriesArray = array();

foreach ($yourArray as $arrayItem) {
   if (!isset($categoriesArray[$arrayItem['category_name']])) {
       $categoriesArray[$arrayItem['category_name']] = array(
           'category_name' => $arrayItem['category_name'],
           'sum' => 0
       );
   }

   $categoriesArray[$arrayItem['category_name']]['sum'] += $arrayItem['amount'];
}

$categoriesArray = json_encode(array_values($categoriesArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $input is your array and $output is the JSON string:

```
$categorysum = [];
array_walk($input, function($el) use (&$categorysum) {
    $categorysum += [$el['category_name'] => ['category_name' => $el['category_name'], 'Sum' => 0]];
    $categorysum[$el['category_name']]['Sum'] += $el['amount'];
});
$output = json_encode(array_values($categorysum));
```